# How to select specific row of a table and calculate the time difference?

Tags: c#, .net, mysql

My idea is this:
 When l enter a Branch Number (int), the compiler will search the table for a column (SunToTime) and obtain its Time value.
 The value will be used to deduct another column (SunFromTime) Time value which lies at the same row.
Hence l can obtain a Time difference. The problem is l don't know how to type out the correct code. The SELECT and WHERE code does not work in my code. Does any1 know how can l fix my code? Here's my code:

```
//This code is wrong.
DataRow[] sunTimeDifference = 
    RetailCamDataSet1.Tables["smBranchWorkingDayInfo"]
        .Select("SunToTime")
        .Where("BranchID=" + convertedBranchID + "") 
    - RetailCamDataSet1.Tables["smBranchWorkingDayInfo"]
        .Select("SunFromTime").Where("BranchID=" + convertedBranchID + "");
```

Comment: I'm not familiar with these `.Select()` and `.Where()` methods that you're using.  Are they part of a specific library?  When you say they don't work, can you be more specific?  Is there an error?

Comment: I searched the internet for this tutorial about .Select() and .Where(). The errors related to:
"Cannot convert from string to 'System.Func<System.Data.DataRow,int,bool>'"
and 
"'System.Data.DataRow[] does not contain a definition for 'Where and the best extension method overload 'System.Linq.Enumerable.Where<TSource>(System.Collections.Generic.IEnumerable<TSource>, System.Func<TSource, int,bool>)' has some invalid arguments.

Comment: Oh, those are the extensions on `IEnumerable`?  Ya, you're definitely using those wrong.  You'll want to find a tutorial on how to use LINQ methods.  For example, instead of `Select("SunToTime")` you would want something like `Select(x => x.SunToTime)`, basically saying that for every row `x` in the results you want to select the `SunToTime` field.  I'm not sure how it works on the `.Tables[]` collection, though, in terms of strong typing.  But if you're able to use LINQ, why even use `DataTable`s in the first place?  Use LINQ to SQL instead.  (Find tutorials on it, it's well-established.)

Answer (score 0):

You are trying to use LINQ statements in the wrong way it seems. They generally take Func methods via lambdas. A more proper approach would be something more like this:

```
 var sunTimeDifference = 
    RetailCamDataSet1.Tables["smBranchWorkingDayInfo"]
        .Where(retailCam=>retailCam.BranchID == convertedBranchID)
        .Select(retailCam=>new{DifferenceValue = SunToTime - SunFromTime);
```

This assumes that `RetailCamDataSet1.Tables["smBranchWorkingDayInfo"]` can be cast as `IEnumerable` and that it has strongly typed objects that match your variables, which I am doubting.

What would normally happen is the following:

- `RetailCamDataSet1.Tables["smBranchWorkingDayInfo"]` would return an IEnumerable
- That IEnumerable would be passed into the `Where` to be filtered using `RetailCamDataSet1.Tables["smBranchWorkingDayInfo"]`'s BranchID against `convertedBranchID`
- That would be passed into the `Select` and an IEnumerable of an anonymous type would be returned. That anonymous type would contain a property named `DifferenceValue` that would be equivalent to `SunToTime` - `SunFromTime`

Here is the MSDN for [SELECT](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb548891.aspx) and [WHERE](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb534803.aspx)

**HOWEVER**, I do not believe that a DataTable will work since it is not strongly typed, nor is it castable to IEnumerable (I am not 100% sure about the latter statement though).

In that case, you would want to do something more like this

```
DataRow[] result = RetailCamDataSet1.Tables["smBranchWorkingDayInfo"]
                       .Select("BranchID=" + convertedBranchID);
foreach(DataRow row in result)
{
    var difference = Int.Parse(row["SunToTime"]) - Int.Parse(row["SunFromTime"]);
    //do something with the difference
}
```

As, David mentioned, if you want to use LINQ to SQL in the way I mentioned above (minus the DataTable), then you should look up some tutorials on the matter...they are aplenty with a google search